# Getting java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner straight out of AP Computer Science.

I'm trying to make an app that converts text input from the user into pig latin, for practice. It's a work in progress but so far i'm getting exceptions.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.ashavolian.piglatin2;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtOut;
    EditText txtIn;
    Button button;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOut);
        txtIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtIn);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String txtTxtIn = txtIn.getText().toString();
                txtOut.setText(translate(txtTxtIn));
            }
        });

    }

    public String translate(String txtTxtIn)
    {
        txtTxtIn += " "; 
        int length = txtTxtIn.length();
        String pigLatin = " ";

        for (int b = 0; b < length; b++) {
            int space = txtTxtIn.indexOf(" ");
            String word = txtTxtIn.substring(0, space);
            int a = word.indexOf("a");
            int e = word.indexOf("e");
            int i = word.indexOf("i");
            int o = word.indexOf("o");
            int u = word.indexOf("u");

            int vowels[] = {a, e, i, o, u};

            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
            {
                if (vowels[c] == -1)
                    vowels[c] += 101;
            }

            for (int d = 0; d < 4; d++)
            {
                if (vowels[d] > -1 && vowels[d] <= vowels[0] && vowels[d] <= vowels[1] && vowels[d] <= vowels[2] && vowels[d] <= vowels[3] && vowels[d] <= vowels[4])
                {
                    word = word.substring(vowels[i] + 1) + word.substring(0,vowels[i]);
                    pigLatin += " " + word;
                }
            }
            txtTxtIn = txtTxtIn.substring(space + 1);
        }

        return pigLatin;
    }

}
```

The exception only occurs when you press the button. Making the Program crash.

Here's the exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ashavolian.piglatin2, PID: 2991
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
    at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:298)
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1087)
    at com.example.ashavolian.piglatin2.MainActivity.translate(MainActivity.java:39)
    at com.example.ashavolian.piglatin2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:27)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: why are you discriminating against vowel `u`?

Comment: ` vowels[c] += 101;` and then you are trying to do `word.substring(vowels[i] + 1)`

Comment: You must provide better conditions for entering this bit here: `word.substring(vowels[i] + 1) + word.substring(0,vowels[i]);`. I think it causes the error, nobody guarantees that word is longer than vowels[i]+1, maybe `i` is at the last spot.

Comment: @JonnyHenly , No i haven't. one reason is i don't know how to. And another is that i'm really trying to learn from mistakes and receive input from you guys. Thanks though, i'll try that as a last resort.

Comment: @fukanchik I'm not sure what you mean by discriminating but thanks for catching the consistency mistake.

Comment: @Vucko That's a good point and i will fix that. But it's not what causes the exception because my testing conditions do not end with a vowel. Any advice as to how to fix that though?

Comment: You are discriminating `u` because you've got 5 vowels and you only use 4 of them, ignoring the last one.

Comment: @fukanchik Doesn't it include 0 though? Starts from 0 including 0 to 4 making that 5 loops.

Comment: @fukanchik Oh wait.. i have to put the `c++;` after the contents of the for loop don't i?

Comment: You have it backwards, receiving input from us should be your last resort and using a debugger should be your first resort.

Comment: @JonnyHenly ok. I still don't know how to though. I tried but i don't really get what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, an exception is thrown when you try to access element in the array with an index, which doesn't actually exist. It's typical situation, when you get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I cannot tell you in which line is a real mistake without debugging the application. Your `translate(String)` method is doing strange stuff and code is not so clean. Nevertheless, I have the following candidates, which could cause that exception:

- `vowels[i]` - `i` variable is calculated by int `i = word.indexOf("i");` and `word` is calculated by `txtTxtIn.substring(0, space);`, but you cannot be sure about length of `txtxTxtIn`, but max index of `vovels` is 4. When `txtTxtIn` has more characters than 5, an exception will be thrown
- `txtTxtIn = txtTxtIn.substring(space + 1);` - here may be similar story as above

My suggestion is to debug this code. Moreover, you could use `List`. It's Java and we have such structures here. It would be much easier to perform operations on strings and chars and harder to make such mistake.

Comment: Woah I had the max loop set for 4 when i meant to have it set to `word.Length()`. I fixed that but the same exact exception shows up. Thanks though.

Comment: If the bug still occurs, try to run the debugger and debug your code step by step until you get an exception. Pay attention to accessing arrays while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Variable i in the following code is the problem.

```
word = word.substring(vowels[i] + 1) + word.substring(0,vowels[i]);
```

Check whether you want the variable i or some other variable.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. i changed it to variable d but it still crashes.